# How to use prepared statements to get results and use it in a while loop?

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, code-injection

I want to use prepared statements instead of my current code:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['checkGame'] != 'Any')
    {
        $game = $_POST['checkGame'];
        $sql="SELECT ipaddress, port FROM servers WHERE game=('$game')";
            $result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($serverConnectionArray, ["address" =>$row['ipaddress'], "port" =>$row['port']]);
    }
    }
```

I've tried:

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $_POST['checkGame'] != 'Any')
    {
        $game = $_POST['checkGame'];
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT ipaddress, port FROM servers WHERE game=?");
        $stmt->bind_param("s", $game);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        $stmt->fetch();
            while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            array_push($serverConnectionArray, ["address" =>$row['ipaddress'], "port" =>$row['port']]);
        $stmt->close();
    }
    }
```

And more. However, I get this error:

Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ...list.php on line 26

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in ...list.php:26 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in ...list.php on line 26

Thanks!

Comment: `$mysqli` isn't defined...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>First of all, you are mixing API styles; the MySQLi extension can be used in two ways: either with the object oriented (OOP) approach (`$mysqli->`) or the procedural approach (the `mysqli_*` functions). You cant mix both styles.</strike> <sup>1</sup>

It appears as though you want to use the OOP style. In that case, you first need to create the actual `mysqli` object (also called an instance of the [`mysqli` class](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli.php)), with something like: <sup>2</sup>

```
$mysqli = new mysqli('127.0.0.1', 'username', 'password', 'dbname');
```

See the [basic examples in the documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.examples-basic.php) for more information on how to proceed after that.

---

<sup>1) See @Fred-ii-'s comment below: it turns out the interfaces *can* actually be mixed. I was not aware of this.</sup>
<sup>2) The question is ambiguous about whether OP simply addressed the wrong variable name, or whether OP completely forgot to instantiate a MySQLi connection in the first place; both would emit the same notice.</sup>

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean this like this "$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);"? Nvm saw your edit.

Comment: @Leyer Yes, but then make sure you use the correct variable name (`$conn->` instead of `$mysqli->`) in the rest of your code, when you want to interact with the connection.

Comment: *"You cant mix both styles."* - That's false. It's not recommented but they do work together. I quote from the manual http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.dual-interface.php under "Mixing styles": *"It is possible to switch between styles at any time. Mixing both styles is not recommended for code clarity and coding style reasons."*

Comment: What you posted doesn't outline what the real problem was and the question was closed in that respect. Oh sure it fixed their code, but that was obvious; they used the wrong variable which is exactly what they posted as the error that they got back: `Notice: Undefined variable: mysqli in ...list.php on line 26` - In using the correct variable, the rest of the code then proceeded in a successful manner.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I was convinced (I even thought I had read it in the manual at some point) that the API styles wouldn't mix. I must have confused this with some other OOP/procedural PHP API. Thank you for pointing this out. And to address your second comment: since OP's code snippet didn't show any instantiation of a connection, I interpreted the question as though OP forgot to do this, in stead of OP simply addressing the wrong variable name, which would both lead to the same notice.

Comment: @DecentDabbler it can be a bit difficult to find those facts in the manuals at times and there are even some that are undocumented. I find those out here on Stack also, so I'm sharing the wealth as it were, *cheers* and you're welcome.

Answer (score -3):

it's look like you didn't defined the object properly.

`$connection = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", $user, $pass);`

Comment: OP is not using the PDO extension, but the MySQLi extension.

Comment: I had the variable misspelled. Thanks!